# dictionary difference operation

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, A and B, and I want to take those key:value pairs that exist in B but not A, and add them to A. I don't want the values of B with matching keys to be added to or overwritten in A.

```
A = {'one':1, 'two':2}
B = {'one':1, 'two':999, 'three':3}
```

I want the resulting dictionary to look like:

```
A = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}
```

I imagine the answer is something like this, but I can't get the value part right.

```
A.update(dict.fromkeys(set(B).difference(A), B.values()))
```

Comment: Why are you trying to cram this into one line? Take a few and it will become much simpler.

Comment: use the `set` class. Create a `set` that contains `A.keys()` and another one that contains `B.keys()`. The `set` should have a difference method

Comment: @user3322273 that's exactly what the OP is already doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
A = {'one':1, 'two':2}
B = {'one':1, 'two':999, 'three':3}

for k,v in B.items():
    A.setdefault(k, v)

print(A)
```

```
{'two': 2, 'one': 1, 'three': 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this:

```
for key in B:
    if key not in A:
        A[key] = B[key]
```

Before you say it's not in one line, I'd say it's quite readable and does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a union?

```
>>> A = {'one':1, 'two':2}
>>> B = {'one':1, 'two':999, 'three':3}
>>> dict(B.items() + A.items())
{'one': 1, 'three': 3, 'two': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

Use {}.update() and set of the keys. With a dict comprehension:

```
>>> A = {'one':1, 'two':2}
>>> B = {'one':1, 'two':999, 'three':3}
>>> A.update({key:B[key] for key in set(B)-set(A)})
>>> A
{'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Or with `dict` and a generator expression:

```
>>> A.update(dict((key,B[key]) for key in set(B)-set(A)))
```